# FluentValidation conditional rules

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation

I want to make a conditional to execute the CPF rule only when dealing with a CPF with `length == 11`, and execute the CNPJ rule only when dealing with a CNPJ with `length > 11`.

However, I realized that even with `When`, both methods are executed (`MustBeAValidCPF` and `MustBeAValidCNPJ`).
Is there a way to run it only when the `When` returns `true`?

```
RuleFor(x => x.Code)
    .NotEmpty()
    .WithMessage(m => "Code cannot be empty")
    .MinimumLength(11)
    .WithMessage(m => "Code minimum length is 11")
    .MustBeAValidCPF()
    .When(x => x.Code?.Length == 11)
    .MustBeAValidCNPJ()
    .When(x => x.Code?.Length > 11);
```

Methods (extensions):

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string> MustBeAValidCPF<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder)
{
    return ruleBuilder.IsValidCPF().WithMessage("CPF is invalid");
}

public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string> MustBeAValidCNPJ<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder)
{
    return ruleBuilder.IsValidCNPJ().WithMessage("CNPJ is invalid");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/conditions.html#conditions), the `When` method has an optional parameter to modify this behavior.

By default:

> If the second parameter is not specified, then it defaults to `ApplyConditionTo.AllValidators`, meaning that the condition will apply to all preceding validators in the same chain.

To achieve what you want, pass `ApplyConditionTo.CurrentValidator` as the second parameter of both calls to `When`:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Code)
    .NotEmpty()
    .WithMessage(m => "Code cannot be empty")
    .MinimumLength(11)
    .WithMessage(m => "Code minimum length is 11")
    .MustBeAValidCPF()
    .When(x => x.Code?.Length == 11, ApplyConditionTo.CurrentValidator)
    .MustBeAValidCNPJ()
    .When(x => x.Code?.Length > 11, ApplyConditionTo.CurrentValidator);
```